# Err TexShop Monterey 12.5.1

Tags: pdftex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Recupero III Liceo.tex/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex: getwd: Operation not permitted

Comment: That error message is from pdflatex and has nothing to do with TeXShop. Please describe the actual context in which you get this error, and provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates it if possible. You should also edit the question and use a title that actually describes the issue. It's possible you need to use the `-shell-escape` option when compiling, but it's hard to tell out of context.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What is the question? You need to give more information.

Comment: I am having this TexShop 4.77 and 3.26 both versions on the Mac

Comment: I fixed both versions by adding the Texshop to the Security & Privacy tab in OS settings .All good to go